# Progress bar crashes when updated from swift file that is not it's viewController

Tags: ios, swift, progress-bar

I have a file in Swift that holds all my queries. And when saving a record with `saveOperation.perRecordProgressBlock` this file call ChatView view controller and updates the progressBarUpdate function.

So far I can get the print within `progressBarUpdate` to print the progress just fine. But when I get to update `progressBarMessage.setProgress(value!, animated: true)` the application just crash with the following error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

If I try to run `progressBarMessage.setProgress(value!, animated: true`) through `viewDidLoad` it updates the progress bar fine, no error. Which means the outlet is working just fine.

Other thing to consider, is that my `print(".... perRecordProgressBlock - CHAT VIEW\(value)")` works just fine. If gets the updates from `Queris.swift`. It is just the progressBarUpdate that is causing issues.

**@ my Queries.swift file option 1**

```
 saveOperation.perRecordProgressBlock = { (recordID, progress) -> Void in
    print("... perRecordProgressBlock \(Float(progress))")
    var chatView = ChatView()
    chatView.progressBarUpdate(Float(progress))
 }
```

**@ my Queries.swift file option 2**

```
 saveOperation.perRecordProgressBlock = { (recordID, progress) -> Void in
    print("... perRecordProgressBlock \(Float(progress))")

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let chatViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ChatViewVC") as! ChatView
    chatViewController.progressBarUpdate(Float(progress))
}
```

**@ ChatView view controller**

```
func progressBarUpdate(value: Float) 
{
    print(".... perRecordProgressBlock - CHAT VIEW\(value)")
    if (value as? Float) != nil 
    {
        progressBarMessage.setProgress(value, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `value` is a non-nil here? 
`progressBarMessage.setProgress(value, animated: true)`

Comment: pretty sure, have a look at the updated code. where I make sure no 'nil' passes to 'progressBarMessage'

Answer (score 0):

```
var chatView = ChatView()
```

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say you are using storyboards/xibs. If so, the above would not be the correct way to instantiate a new view controller. [Here's some information on the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131693/instantiate-view-controller-from-storyboard-vs-creating-new-instance) (the question refers to Objective-C but the concept is the same in Swift)

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let chatViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("identifier-you-set-in-storyboard") as! ChatView
```

Where `identifier-you-set-in-storyboard` is [set in the interface builder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13867565/2446155) (the linked question is old but illustrates the concept, the field label might have changed in newer versions)

---

If by some off chance you are creating you are setting up your views in code (as opposed to storyboards), you'd need to call `chatView.loadView()` before `chatView.progressBarUpdate...`. (Or just try to access the `view` property and it should call `loadView` for you.)

Comment: I've made some update to my question with your suggestions. Still not working. Note that the print statement within 'func progressBarUpdate' works just fine. Just the progress bar that is failing.

Comment: @GuiSoySauce Try adding `let _ = chatViewController.view` before calling progressBarUpdate. This will force your view controller to actually load the view and set the progress view property properly.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are instantiating the `viewController` is not the right way and hence the crash/nil val. `viewController` loads its view hierarchy only when something sends it a `view` message. The system will do this by its own when to put the `view` hierarchy on the screen. And it happens after calls like `prepareForSegue:sender:` and `viewWillAppear:` , `loadView()`, `self.view`.

So here your outlets are still nil since it is not loaded yet.

Just try to force your `viewController` to call `self.view` and then access the functions from that `viewController`.