# TableView seguing and cause unexpectedly nil returned

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard, segue

Here is my current setup:

`MainMenuViewController` -> `SubMenuViewController` -> `UserInputViewController` -> `ResultViewController`

All of my view controllers contains a `tableView`.

When a user taps on a cell in `MainMenuViewControlle`, it will segue to `SubMenuViewController`. All fine and dandy.

Here is where it gets tricky, in `SubMenuViewController`, there are cells that needs to instantiate another `SubMenuViewController` because the sub menu options can be several levels deep.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        guard let selectedNode = node?.childenNode[indexPath.row] else {
            return
        }

        if selectedNode.isLeaveNode() {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "userInput", sender: self)
        } else {
            let subMenuViewController = SubMenuViewController(node: selectedNode)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(subMenuViewController, animated: true)
        }
```

When there are no child nodes, then it will segue to `UserInputViewController`, but when there are more options, it needs to instantiate another `SubMenuViewController` and the `tableView` will populate itself based on cell the user had tapped previously until `selectedNode.isLeaveNode()` is true (which means there won't be any child nodes).

This problem is when this code runs :

```
    let subMenuViewController = SubMenuViewController(node: selectedNode)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(subMenuViewController, animated: true)
```

it give me the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

From where I registered my cells which is here:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
let nib = UINib(nibName: "SubMenuTableViewCell", bundle: bundle)
tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SubMenuCell")
```

All my tableView cells are instantiated using a xib file, and I have registered my cells in `viewDidLoad()`

Can anybody see the problem?

**UPDATE**

Here is the rest of my code:

`UIViewController`

```
class SubMenuViewController: UIViewController {

    var node: Node?

    init(node: Node) {
        self.node = node
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        self.navigationItem.title = node?.value.rawValue

        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "SubMenuTableViewCell", bundle: bundle)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SubMenuCell")
    }
}
```

`UITableViewDataSource`

```
extension SubMenuViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return node!.childCount
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("called")

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SubMenuCell", for: indexPath) as! SubMenuTableViewCell
        let desciptionModule = node?.childenNode[indexPath.row].value

        let description = Modules.description(module: desciptionModule!)

        cell.title.text = description.main
        cell.subtitle.text = description.sub

        return cell

    }
}
```

`UITableViewDelegate`

```
extension SubMenuViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 68
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        guard let selectedNode = node?.childenNode[indexPath.row] else {
            return
        }

        if selectedNode.isLeaveNode() {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "userInput", sender: self)
        } else {
            let subMenuViewController = SubMenuViewController(node: selectedNode)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(subMenuViewController, animated: true)
        }

    }  
}
```

Comment: Is your `subMenuViewController` being instantiated ? What you get if you print it right after your `let` ?

Comment: Add your SubMenuViewController initialization code, please.

Comment: Please see update, thanks

Comment: @BrendonCheung On which exact lane of code do you catch the crash? Does this outlet `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!` connected with storyboard? Do you use `prepareForSegue:` function?

Comment: @VasiliiMuravev The error was in `tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SubMenuCell")`, and yes my `tableView` is connect and no I did not use a `prepareForSegue`. On that thought, we can't use `prepareForSegue` because there is no segue in the storyboard. The `SubMenuViewController` instantiate itself

Comment: If you want to instantiate a view controller like that, you have some more work to do. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131693/instantiate-view-controller-from-storyboard-vs-creating-new-instance#26131792

Comment: I see, so instead of doing `let subMenuViewController = SubMenuViewController(node: selectedNode)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(subMenuViewController, animated: true)`, I should be using the storyboard to instantiate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

The problem lies in the fact that I instantiated my view controller wrong. The line:

`let subMenuViewController = SubMenuViewController(node: selectedNode)`

only return a raw object with no outlets, that is why I was getting the optional nil error because there weren't a tableView to start with.

The correct approach would be to instantiate it using your storyboard. Each view controller has a storyboard property as an optional, since my view controller exists in a storyboard, that property will not be nil.

Instead of doing this:

```
let subMenuViewController = SubMenuViewController(node: selectedNode)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(subMenuViewController, animated: true)
```

I actually needed to do this:

```
let subMenuViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController("SubMenuViewController")
```

That way I know for sure that my subMenuViewController will contain my tableView property which is an IBOutlet from storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

**In your `viewDidLoad()` method, make sure to do the following:**

Based on the code you've posted, you might be having issues with this line:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
```

I would recommend replacing it with the following line:

```
let bundle = Bundle(forClass: self)
```

or

```
let bundle = Bundle.main
```

If you're still having trouble with this, then try modifying the following lines of code:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "SubMenuTableViewCell", bundle: bundle)
```

to

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "SubMenuTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
```

**In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` `UITableViewControllerDelegate` method, include the following lines:**

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SubMenuCell") as? UITableViewCell

if cell == nil {
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "SubMenuTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SubMenuCell")
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SubMenuCell") as SubMenuTableViewCell!
}

cell.configure(data: data[indexPath.row])
tableView.reloadData()
return cell
```

**Note**

1. Make sure that the UITableViewCell's reuseIdentifier is "SubMenuCell"
2. Make sure that the SubMenuTableViewCell.xib file's owner is `SubMenuTableViewCell`
3. Make sure the Module does not say "None" (i.e. the Module should be the name of your Project's Target).
4. Make sure to call `tableView.reloadData()` in your `viewDidLoad()` function.

Comment: Thanks, the strange thing is that when `MainMenuViewController` segues into `SubMenuViewController`, everything works! but as soon as I tried to instantiate the very same controller (`SubMenuViewController`), it fails. I tried your approach and the error still persists

Comment: I added an extra line inside the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method that reloads the tableView. Try that out.