# UIViewController initialized via UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController does not deinit during unit test when set to nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, deinit

I can't figure out why a UIViewController instantiated with UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController does not deinit when initalized in a unit test

Here's the code that I expect to deinit but does not:

```
func testDoesNotDeinit() throws {
    var strongViewController: ViewController? =
        UIStoryboard(
            name: "Main",
            bundle: Bundle(for: ViewController.self)
        )
        .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController

    print("set nil")
    strongViewController = nil
    print("post set nil")
}
```

The result is:

```
set nil
post set nil
*** deinit *** // From deinit {} function in UIViewController
```

When the UIViewController is initialized programmatically it will deinitialize properly

```
func testDoesDeinit() throws {
    var strongViewController: ViewController? = ViewController()

    XCTAssertNotNil(strongViewController)
    print("set nil")
    strongViewController = nil
    print("post set nil")
    XCTAssertNil(strongViewController)
}
```

with result:

```
set nil
*** deinit *** // From deinit {} function in UIViewController
post set nil
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When I tried with a sample vc, both are deallocated and called `deinit`. It can be depend on your subviews and their references in *Main* storyboard. (as reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26131792/3835963) answer.)

Answer (score 0):

I set a breakpoint at `print("post set nil")` and inspected the memory graph at that point in time. I saw that the VC is being retained by an instance of `UIStoryboardScene`:

[image]

`UIStoryboardScene` seems to be a private API. The only thing I can find about it is [this header](https://developer.limneos.net/index.php?ios=13.1.3&framework=UIKitCore.framework&header=UIStoryboardScene.h). This is probably an implementation detail of `instantiateViewController`.